# Android calculator crash

Tags: java, android, crash, calculator

I just started learning Android today, and my program is crashing when I run it. Sorry for my incompetence, help would be greatly appreciated. I have been trying to figure this out. I have been following youtube tutorials, but the teacher's eclipse is an older version, making it very difficult to learn. Here is the code:

```
package com.audiack.newproj;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
LinearLayout layout1;
EditText number1Text;
EditText number2Text;
Button calcButton,derp;
TextView answer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    layout1 = new LinearLayout(this);
    number1Text = new EditText(this);
    number2Text = new EditText(this);
    calcButton = new Button(this);
    answer = new TextView(this);

    layout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    answer.setText("0");
    calcButton.setText("you suck at math bro");

    calcButton.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) multiplyClicked);

    layout1.addView(number1Text);
    layout1.addView(number2Text);       
    layout1.addView(calcButton);
    layout1.addView(answer);

    setContentView(layout1);
}
    private OnClickListener multiplyClicked = new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) 
        {
            String firstString = number1Text.getText().toString();
            String secondString = number2Text.getText().toString();
            double firstNum = Double.parseDouble(firstString);
            double secondNum = Double.parseDouble(secondString);
            double result = firstNum * secondNum;
            String resultString = String.valueOf(result);
            answer.setText(resultString);
        }

    };
```

}

Comment: What is the stack trace? Like what is the reason it is crashing? Leave a stack trace if you could.

Comment: Please update the title of your question. Saying *my application crashes* means nothing, is like going to a doctor and saying *I have a headache, heal me now*.

Comment: I have no idea how to get the stack trace...so sorry

Comment: Check the Logcat stacktrace or the Consolve view output. There it will say what problem your application had (lot of *caused by* clauses, we need you to copy/paste it here [yes, all of it]).

Comment: When your application has failed. Go to eclipse and look for Logcat and copy the code that should be in read. Should say "threw an exception at ...." and "caused by ....." with a lot more text which helps us find where the error happened within the code.

Comment: 06-01 15:37:57.439: E/AndroidRuntime(21957): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.audiack.newproj.MainActivity$1 cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnClickListener

Comment: Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: That is what caused the error. you have an invalid cast

Comment: Sorry i know so little, care to elaborate? I know what a cast is, but I am not sure where in the program the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

You were using the wrong import for the onClickListener you want to use the android.view.View OnClickHander

```
private OnClickListener multiplyClicked = new OnClickListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
```

and change your import to this

```
import android.view.View;
```

You have imported a differnt EventHandler which was throughing the error since you were calling it like this

```
calcButton.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) multiplyClicked);
```

But in your imports you were using a different OnClickHandler so it used that and was giving a InvalidCastException since they are two differnt EventHandlers.

So if you remove the

```
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
```

and change the

```
calcButton.setOnClickListener(multiplyClicked);
```

you should solve that invalid cast.

Comment: it is giving me this error now: 06-01 15:37:57.439: E/AndroidRuntime(21957): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.audiack.newproj.MainActivity$1 cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnClickListener

Comment: sorry wrong error XD here is the right one: The method onClick(View) of type new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){} must override 
 or implement a supertype method

Comment: This is because you need to call it `new View.OnClickListener` or do a static import: `import static android.view.View.*`. IMO I would prefer the former.